# Problem when adding a dependency to maven

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, pom.xml

I have a very basic springboot project that has the following pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>



    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

I want to add this dependency: https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.apache.hive/hive-jdbc/3.1.2/jar

So I added in the dependencies :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
  <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

However, when I have this in my pom.xml, I have the following errors:

> The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved
>
> The container 'Maven Dependencies' references non existing library
> '/home/hduser/.m2/repository/jdk/tools/jdk.tools/1.6/jdk.tools-1.6.jar'
>
> Missing artifact jdk.tools:jdk.tools:jar:1.6

I am using java 11 and my IDE as well as JAVA_HOME is set to java 11.

How can I solve this ?

---

Edit 1:

```
mvn clean package


------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.454 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-10-06T10:51:20+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project dataanalytics: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.bla:dataanalytics:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact jdk.tools:jdk.tools:jar:1.6 at specified path /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/../lib/tools.jar -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Comment: Please run a build with `mvn clean package` and report the result.

Comment: @JFabianMeier Updated the answer with your request.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Interpretting the error message

> Could not find artifact jdk.tools:jdk.tools:jar:1.6 at specified path
> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/../lib/tools.jar

The tools.jar file is supplied by the JDK - looks like 1.6 is referenced from the included dependency - suggest you explicitly exclude it:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
  <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.2</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>jdk.tools</artifactId>
      <groupId>jdk.tools</groupId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>

</dependency>
```

Comment: It should be noted that with this option you lose access to the functionality that depends on the excluded artifact, which may or may not be desirable or acceptable. Generally, exclusions should be a last resort.